# after adding v-on:click via jquery click trigger not fire Vuejs method

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I want to fire vuejs method from my conditional statement so when ever validation success then i need to check the all required field is actually has some value then i add a attribute via jquery.

```
 if(id == 'submit'){
                    if (checkValidation()) {
                        $("#error").hide();
                        $(this).attr("v-on:click", "storeApplication");
                        document.getElementById('submit').click();
                    }else{
                        $("#error").show();
                    }
                }
```

I checked code when all input is field has value then attribute update on click but my vuejs method storeApplication not fire.... no error in console

Comment: that's not how vue works ... in my experience, if you use jquery with vue, you aren't doing it right

Comment: I'm using inline template in Laravel blade file.

Comment: that's still not how vue works - you don't just add `v-on:click` to an arbitrary element

Comment: you can display all the code you want ... you can't use vue like you are trying to

Comment: so how i can fire that method?

Comment: By using vue OR jquery - decide which

Comment: suggest me both solution

Comment: You can use jQuery with Vue but not like this, there are rules that you need to obey. You can't modify the elements and expect Vue to update the logic, Vue boot up by reading the tempalte and then connecting the dynamic parts they can be then removed from the document the rest is in memory. What you can use with jQuery is that if you have library like plugin you can try to connect it with Vue but you should not mix logic in application, you should do everything in Vue way.